# Insert row to database based on form values not currently in database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2013 and I am trying to insert rows to a table but I don't want any duplicates. Basically if not exists in table enter the data to table. I have tried to using 'Not Exists' and 'Not in' and currently it still does not insert to table. Here is my code if I remove the where condition then it inserts to table but If I enter same record it duplicates. Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO [UB-04s] ( consumer_id, prov_id, total_charges, [non-covered_chrgs], patient_name )
VALUES ([Forms]![frmHospitalEOR]![client_ID], [Forms]![frmHospitalEOR]![ID], Forms![frmHospitalEOR].[frmItemizedStmtTotals].Form.[TOTAL BILLED], Forms![frmHospitalEOR].[frmItemizedStmtTotals].Form.[TOTAL BILLED], [Forms]![frmHospitalEOR]![patient_name])
WHERE [Forms]![frmHospitalEOR]![ID]
NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT prov_id FROM [UB-04s]);
```

Comment: you could start by designing your database in a way that it won't allow the insert. `ALTER TABLE [UB-04s] ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ_UB-04s] UNIQUE (prov_id);`

Comment: ^ I don't believe this will work because I also want to be able to have null values for prov_id, not all records will have a prov_id

Comment: Are you using ms-access-2010 or 2013?  Why the sql-server tag?

Comment: Im using access 2013 front end sql server backend

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use WHERE in this kind of SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname) VALUES ('value');
```

You can add a constraint to the database, like a unique index, then the insert will fail with an error message. It is possible to have multiple NULL values for several rows, the unique index makes sure that rows with values are unique.

To avoid these kind of error messages you can build a procedure or use code to check data first, and then perform some action - like do the insert or cancel.

This select could be used to check data:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [UB-04s] WHERE prov_id = [Forms]![frmHospitalEOR]![ID]
```

It will return number of rows with the spesific value, if it is 0 then you are redy to run the insert.